# Report Builder 2.0: Display certain rows based on certain conditions

Tags: reporting-services

I have a table which has, apart from others, two columns named Partition_Name and Xkey. What I want to  is, when an user logs in to the system, it has an Xkey which is found in the Xkey column, to display the rows "linked" to his xkey (the rows which have their xkey). Moreover, I have to check the partition_name column. If a user logs in, and the corespondend of his xkey  in the partition_name is EP, I have to display ALL the rows, not only those related to his xkey.

I've done the first part (display the rows based on certain xkeys) but I can`t figure out how to display all the rows if the partition_name of that xkey is EP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do that in RB 3.0; I don't know how 2.0 is different, but this may work.

- I don't know how your system is set up, but we'll assume there's a
  way for you to determine who the user is and what the user's
  partition_name is. You need to set up a hidden parameter to be set to
  the value of the user's partition_name; we'll call this parameter
  PN_param; you also need to set up another hidden filter, which we'll call xkey_param.
- Set up a filter on your dataset. Set the Value to [xkey] or
  whatever the name of the column is. Make sure the Type is text.
- Set the Operator to =
- Set the expression to the following:

  =Iif(Parameters!PN_param.Value = "EP", "*", Parameters!xkey_param.Value)

Give that a try.

Comment: @adrianculea I noticed an error in my answer; it would have you filtering by partition_name rather than xkey. I've edited my answer in the first and fourth bullet points accordingly.